# How to join all of the polygons that intersects and leave others without change in postgis?

Tags: postgis

What I need is to unite intersecting polygons in a single geometry and leave others without change.

[image]

I am able to do this using the following query, which unites all of the polygons into a single geometry and then dumps it to the separate ones.

```
INSERT INTO unioned(geom)
SELECT ST_MULTI((ST_Dump(ST_Union(geom))).geom) from footprints;
```

[image]

The problem is that I have more than a million rows in a database and `ST_Union` operation never ends. Is there any way to achieve the same without joining all of the geometries?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a different approach that I expect will be much faster for the type of data you showed above:

```
ST_UnaryUnion(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(geom))) FROM footprints;
```

This query:

1. Uses [`ST_ClusterIntersecting`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html) to finds groups of building footprints that form a "chain of intersection", and sticks each group into a `GeometryCollection`. Returns an array.
2. Uses [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-array.html) to the array of geometry collections into a row for each geometry collection.
3. Uses [`ST_UnaryUnion`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_UnaryUnion.html) to union the items within each geometry collection.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @dbaston. Do you know why `ST_ClusterIntersecting` returns geometry with SRID=0 ? How this could be solved? Trying to execute the following query:
`INSERT INTO fixed_footprints(geom)
SELECT ST_UnaryUnion(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(geom)))
  as geom FROM footprints;` I got the following error:
`[22023] ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)`

Comment: think I solved this: ```INSERT INTO fixed_footprints(geom)
SELECT ST_Multi(st_setsrid(ST_UnaryUnion(unnest(ST_ClusterIntersecting(geom))), 4326))
  as geom FROM footprints;``` Will try this out on a bigger set

Comment: @SerheyLadonya looks like the SRID issue is a bug in `ST_ClusterIntersecting`. Thanks for pointing it out, I will get it fixed.